# Why is ng-template in Angular 10 rendered twice?

Tags: angular, angular-template

I figured out a problem with twice rendered components when a `ng-template` and `ngTemplateOutlet` are used. But why?

**HTML:**

```
<ng-template #options>
    <h3>I'm template</h3>
    <sidebar-options></sidebar-options>
</ng-template>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <aside class="order-2">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="options"></ng-container>
        </aside>
        <div class="col order-1">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, ChangeDetectorRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'sidebar-options',
    templateUrl: './sidebar-options.component.html',
})
export class SidebarOptionsComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) container: ViewContainerRef;
    @Input('types') types: OptionType[];

    constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('ini');
    }
}
```

How can I prevent that the `SidebarOptionsComponent`is rendered twice?

Comment: On a first glance I can't see anything wrong with the code. Which part exactly is rendered twice? Does the `<sidebar-options>` component appear twice? Could you maybe share parts of the resulting html? Also, are you sure this is the only usage of the component, the only outlet using this template and there's no loop around the whole block?

Comment: @Grochni `<sidebar-options>` is rendered twice. So the `console.log` from the `ngInit()` appears twice. The component is definitively used once.

Comment: @Grochni the template itself is rendered once and the next time when the `ngTemplateOutlet` is called. I checked this with comment out the `ngTemplateOutlet="..."`

Comment: I just created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-targxr?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.html) with the code you provided and the `console.log` is only printed once. So the error is likely outside of the code you shared. My guess would be that also the surrounding component is initialized twice.

Comment: @Grochni I could find the problem. In `ngAfterContentInit` I created was running in a switch/case without a breaking conditions and so multiple components were created. Too stupid! But thank you for your help!

Comment: @Lars I am facing the same issue . Except the component is not rendered twice but it goes into the constructor twice. Is this also your situation  ?